# How to add a standalone window to powershell ise

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I want to create a usercontrol for Powershell ISE, I have searched how to add add-on to the right pane of the ide, is there a way to popup a standalone window when I click a button from my custom add-on in the right pane?